# Authorize.net form not display in magento2 custom page

Tags: magento2, authorize.net, custompage

I am trying to display custom Authorize.net and for that I have override Magento\Payment\Block\Form\Container. I got the Authorize payment method radio but not able to get form to dispaly. 
[image]
can any one help?

to get above payment method I have override Magento\Payment\Block\Form\Container and layout as given below:

```
<block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Customer\Payment\Method\Form" template="customer/payment/method/form.phtml" name="payment_methods">
```

my form.phtml code is:

```
<?php <?php if ($block->hasMethods()): ?>
<div id="order-billing_method_form">
    <dl class="payment-method">
    <?php
        $_methods       = $block->getMethods();
        $_methodsCount  = count($_methods);
        $_counter = 0;
    ?>
    <?php foreach ($_methods as $_method): $_code = $_method->getCode(); $_counter++; ?>
        <dt class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <?php if ($_methodsCount > 1): ?>
            <input id="p_method_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_code ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]"
                   title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_method->getTitle()) ?>"
                   onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_code ?>')"<?php if ($block->getSelectedMethodCode() == $_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?>
                   class="admin__control-radio<?php if ($_counter == $_methodsCount) : ?> validate-one-required-by-name<?php endif; ?>"/>
        <?php else :?>
            <span class="no-display">
                <input id="p_method_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_code ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_code ?>" type="radio"
                       name="payment[method]" class="admin__control-radio" checked="checked"/>
            </span>
        <?php endif;?>

            <label class="admin__field-label" for="p_method_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_method->getTitle()) ?></label>
        </dt>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
    <dl class="pay-button">
        <dt>
            <button class="action tocart primary" title="Pay Installment" type="submit">
                <span><?php echo __("Pay"); ?></span>
            </button>
        </dt>
    </dl>
</div>
```

All ok and all payment method display properly but authorized.net form not apears on click of 'authorized.net'.

Can Anyone Help me?